# BibTeX enumeration is missing

Tags: bibtex, ieee-style

At the moment I need to write a short paper in LaTeX and gather all my references with BibTeX.
Currently I'm using the bibliographystyle "ieeetr" and the citations in the text look like they should.

However, for some reason at the list of all my references the enumerations are missing. The entries are just listed without the corresponding number.

[image]

The used document class is

```
\documentclass[prodmode]{acmlarge}
```

The references are generated by

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}  
\bibliography{gameanalysis}
```

What's wrong? Is something important missing?

Edit: Compilable example

What you need:
[acmlarge.cls](https://github.com/essepuntato/rash/blob/master/cls/acmlarge.cls)

My tex file:

```
\documentclass[prodmode]{acmlarge}

% Metadata Information
\acmVolume{2}
\acmNumber{3}
\acmArticle{1}
\articleSeq{1}
\acmYear{2010}
\acmMonth{5}

% Package to generate and customize Algorithm as per ACM style
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\SetAlFnt{\algofont}
\SetAlCapFnt{\algofont}
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\algofont}
\SetAlCapHSkip{0pt}
\IncMargin{-\parindent}
\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{ALGORITHM}

\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

% Page heads
\markboth{Me, Myself \& I}{My topic}

% Title portion
\title{My Title}
\author{Me, Myself \& I
\affil{My University}
}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Business Simulation Games}

Business Simulation Games are a sub-genre of simulation games and are also known as Tycoon Games \cite{WikipediaListOfTycoonGames} \cite[p.~71]{ErnestAdams}. The focus of these types of games is on the management of economic processes through the perspective of a business. \cite[p.~527]{ErnestAdams} \newline
According to the definition of ``Pure Business Simulation Games`` by Ernest Adams in his book about ``Fundamentals of Game Design`` \cite[p.~536]{ErnestAdams}, games in this sub-genre are abstract and focused numerical analysis. Most published games fall outside this definition, because they emphasize the aspect of business decisions and often provide creative graphical layer. Thus the player is able to not just see the simulation in numbers, but also structures that exist in the virtual world of the game.\newline
Looking at the aspect of realism from the player's point of view, there is a high interest in realistic simulation achieved by accurate algorithms and plausible data. For each player's action in-game there is also an expected realistic in-game consequence. \cite[p.~36]{ErnestAdams} Christine Elgood, who specializes in the subject of design, facilitation and creation of simulation games, considers a good one has to ``mirror the real world`` and features ``[...] content which is accurate and believable`` \cite{ChristineElgood}.


% Bibliography
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}  
\bibliography{issue}

\end{document}
```

My bib file (I had to remove the urls...):

```
@Book{ErnestAdams,
  author =       "Ernest Adams",
  title =        "Fundamentals of Game Design",
  publisher =    "Pearson Prentice Hall",
  year =         "2009",
  address =      "",
  edition =      "2nd.",
  editor =   "",
  volume =   "",
  number =   "",
  series =   "",
  month =    "",
  note =   "",
}

@misc{ChristineElgood,
    key         = {Christine Elgood},
    title       = {How do you create effective business simulation games? - Elgood's 10 Step Design Process},
    year        = 2011
}

@misc{GoldenAgeOfVideoGames,
    key         = {Encyclopedia Gamia},
    title       = {Golden age of video games},
    note        = {},
    year        = 2016
}

@article{ChrisCrawford,
 author = {Sharon Darling},
 title = {Birth of a computer game},
 journal = {Compute!},
 issue_date = {February 1985},
 number = {57},
 month = {February},
 year = {1985},
}

@misc{WikipediaListOfTycoonGames,
    key         = {List of business simulation video games},
    title       = {List of business simulation video games},
    year        = 2016
}
```

Comment: Welcome, a compilable but minimal example would be great to reproduce your issue. A link to the template is also needed.

Comment: @Johannes_B I've added an example ;)
At the moment I'm using TexPad, an all in one LaTeX editor for mac. Theoretically, it should invoke a re-run of bibtex.

Comment: are you sure that you should be using an IEEE bibliography style with an ACM journal class?

Comment: I'm free which style to use, but I don't like the ACM reference style. Furthermore, when using the `\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format-Journals}` style I get some errors because of unescaped chars in the urls and I can't fix them. So numbers would be the best choice in my opinion.

Comment: @Vetterjack but you can only choose bib styles compatible with the class unless you are free to use a different class.

Comment: OK, thank you all :) It seems I have to go on with the ACM reference style and need to somehow fix my bib file :D

Answer (score 2):

The class file documents

```
%% Bibliographic cite forms needed:
%%
%%  \cite{key}
%%    which produces citations with author list and year.
%%    eg. [Brown 1978; Jarke, et al. 1985]
%%  \citeA{key}
%%    which produces citations with only the author list.
%%    eg. [Brown; Jarke, et al.]
%%  \citeN{key}
%%    which produces citations with the author list and year, but
%%    can be used as nouns in a sentence; no brackets appear around
%%    the author names, but only around the year.
%%      eg. Shneiderman [1978] states that......
%%    \citeN should only be used for a single citation.
%%    \citeNN{refkey1,refkey2} for author [ref1year; ref2year]
%%    \citeyear{key}
%%        which produces the year information only, within brackets.
%%
%% Abbreviated author lists use the ``et al.'' construct.
%%
%% The above are examples of required ACM bibliographic cite formats needed.
```

So you need to use a bibliography style that matches these requirements, ieeetr clearly doesn't and you end up with a mixture of named and numeric conventions. the ACM's sample document uses

```
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
```

If you use that you get no numbers:

[image]

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}` doesn't work for me: `I couldn't open style file ACM-Reference-Format.bst`

Comment: @Vetterjack it is in the ACM latex template zip file (I just got it to make this answer) see the LaTeX link at https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template

Comment: I got this template from my instructor. `\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format-Journals}` seems to work! :)